# MUI add custom colors and use Styleoverride on custom color

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have added a custom color to my project and want to have this color available for example the button in the theme styleoverrides.

Add of new color:

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  
  interface Palette {
    //Add of new Colors in the palette
    green: Palette["primary"];
    
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    green: PaletteOptions["primary"];
    
  }
  
}
```

Then adding the color to the button

```
declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    green: true;
  }
}
```

And also the color in the create theme

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    green: {
      main: "#B7F235",
      
    },
    
  },
});
```

Now I wanted to try and target that color and use, for example, a different style on the text when a button has this 'green' as color prop.

```
components: {
  
    MuiButton: {
      
      styleOverrides: {
        
        containedGreen: {
          //custom styles here for button that has variant contained and color green

      },
    },
},
},
```

Is this somehow possible?